# Error on Running Selenium Webdriver in Jenkins

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins

I am getting bellow error. I am running ant task on jenkins for running testcases..

```
[testng] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host    127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
[testng] Error: no display specified
[testng] Error: no display specified
```

Please provide me the solution for this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Dit try manualy if the address 127.0.0.1:7055 is reachable and selenium server is running?

Comment: i have add libraries for selenium server in build.xml. Do i need to run separately selenium server on linux?

when i check 7055 port. It shows me bellow message.
nc -zv 127.0.0.1 7055
localhost [127.0.0.1] 7055 (?) : Connection refused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project configuration you should have an option:

```
Start Xvfb before the build, and shut it down after
```

Here you can specifiy what display should selenium use via the property `Xvfb specific displayname`. You should set it up to 0. If you don't have that option you should install the xvfb plugin.

Alternatively ssh into the worker and write `export DISPLAY=:0.0`